# how to add local scss styles to svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I am loading a .scss from a svelte component like so:

```
<script>
  import './CancelOrder.scss'
</script>
```

it works for the most part. however, I found out that styles in my scss may affect globally, without any "global:" modifier.
for example, in my CancelOrder.scss I have:

```
h1 {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

this would affect all h1 components in the project globally.
how do I narrow it down, so only the component that loads it would be affected?

my package.json has:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution and it's awesome - works exactly as in react/cssmodules.
very clear installation instructions. no hassle.

it's a library called [svelte-preprocess-cssmodules](https://github.com/micantoine/svelte-preprocess-cssmodules)
thanks @micantoine

Answer (score 2):

You can move the import to the style tag which by default will only apply rules in a scoped way:

```html
<style lang="scss">
  @import './CancelOrder.scss';
</style>
```

(If the build system does not provide it already, you have to add [`svelte-preprocess`](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess) to the Svelte config.)

Comment: I just checked it, it compiles, but the name of the class stays naked, i.e. the class still has the name .macContainer whereas I expect .macContainer-48af843 (as an example)

Comment: That is strange. I remember such imports being scoped and the `svelte-preprocess` docs show an example of `@import` being nested inside `:global` to prevent scoping.

Comment: I'm using `svelte: 4.0.0` `sass: 1.69.5`, and `svelte-preprocess: 5.1.0`. It works and creates scoped classnames. I had to only add `sass` and `svelte-preprocess` along with the `lang="scss"` attribute to my existing sveltekit project.

Answer (score -1):

1. Install Svelte preprocess and Node SASS. The first step is to install 2 dev dependencies onto your Svelte project.
2. Configure svelte-preprocess to rollup config file.
3. Start styling away with SASS.